# How to make a ListView-Control behave like a ListBox-Control?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, listbox

Because I would like to color every single element differently, I decided for the `ListView` instead of the `ListBox`, which can only colour all elements at once.

That means it should, so to speak, have only one column and insert the elements among each other, comparable to the command `listBox.Items.Insert(0, "Item")`.

Which properties do I need to change in order to achieve that?

I already tried setting the `View` Property to `View.List` but as soon as there are too many elements in a row, it continues to insert the elements into a second row that I didn't even create and also can't find when I'm looking at `Edit Columns`...

Comment: Just for your information, you can also use an owner-drawn `ListBox` to have different color for items.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set the `View` to `Details` and set the `HeaderStyle` to `None`, and then by adding a column and setting its size to  `-1` force the column to use the same width as `ListView`:

```
this.listView1.View = View.Details;
this.listView1.HeaderStyle = ColumnHeaderStyle.None;
this.listView1.FullRowSelect = true;
this.listView1.Columns.Add("", -2);
this.listView1.Items.Add("Something");
this.listView1.Items.Add("Something else").BackColor = Color.Red;
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked pretty well! Do you also know which property to set in order to let a scrollbar appear when the string is too long for the ListView-Control? Currently I'm only getting "..." at the end of the line.

Comment: Scrollbar will appear automatically if there are enough items in the `ListView`. If the number of items is that much which the `ListView` should show scrollbars, then it's better to set width of the column after inserting all items. You should know `this.listView1.Columns[0].Width = -2;` will set the width of the column to the width of the `ListView`.